# Error:Execution failed for task ':Find Me:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I have a problem with the my app! build.gradle sync and without  errors, but when I want to run the app  error ! this is error :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':Find
>   Me:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
>
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files
>   copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
>     File1: C:\Users****\workspace\Find Me\libs\httpclient-4.5.1.jar
>
> File2: C:\Users****\workspace\Find Me\libs\httpclient-cache-4.5.1.jar
>
> File3: C:\Users****\workspace\Find Me\libs\httpclient-win-4.5.1.jar
>
> File4: C:\Users****\workspace\Find Me\libs\httpcore-4.4.3.jar

and its build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':android-support-v7-appcompat')
    compile project(':CircularImageView')
    compile project(':FacebookSDK')
    compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
    compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
    compile project(':FacebookSDK')
    compile project(':android-support-v7-appcompat')
    compile project(':CircularImageView')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your grandle file you have `compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
    compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
    compile project(':FacebookSDK')
    compile project(':android-support-v7-appcompat')
    compile project(':CircularImageView')` 2 times

Delete them and only use each once

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
compile project(':android-support-v7-appcompat')
compile project(':CircularImageView')
compile project(':FacebookSDK')
compile project(':google-play-services_lib')

}

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
}
```

**EDIT:**  Add these lines inside android{}

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
```

Comment: @user2003857 can you tell me the reason you  use compile project? Are you editing these files?

Comment: this project on eclipse and i export and import to android studio , web based project and yes i'm editing these files

Answer (score 0):

As @VygintasB said remove the duplicate dependencies and try adding this block in your module level build.gradle file, The error saying ***duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE*** so just exclude those and try

```
android {
 //.....
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
       }     

   }
```

Comment: thank you for answer .thank you for answer. made this error ! Error:(2, 0) Could not find method packagingOptions() for arguments [build_7m54jl7uaw8y6qoof85j6ic93$_run_closure1@41a63d94] on project ':Find Me' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: @user2003857 where did u put the packagingOptions() block? Please put inside android block of gradle file